# Can I create method sleep() for construction try/catch for Thread.sleep. If I cant, tell me problem with it

Tags: java, try-catch

Example:

```
private void sleep(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What problems can there be because of this. And are there any problems in taking out try/catch blocks separately

Answer (score 0):

If this method is called on a thread that has interrupt called on it, then this method can reset the flag, keeping the thread from knowing it got interrupted. When sleep throws InterruptedException it resets the flag. If anything else in this thread needs to know an interruption happened then the flag should be restored by calling Thread.currentThread().interrupt() in the catch block.

If the thread doesn’t use the interrupt flag then this isn’t a problem. There is lots of code where the checked InterruptedException is an inconvenience and they just want to squelch the exception. This is pretty normal.

I’m not sure what you mean about “taking out try and catch blocks separately”.  The try-catch here makes sure the checked exception thrown by the sleep method does not get thrown to the caller. Take it out and there is no point to this method.